# Combobox Background Color Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

How to set a WPF Combobox's "background color" like winform "BackColor" when IsEditable is true?

I tried to set the background property but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code if you are asking about WPF. But, I am not sure whether you are asking the WPF or not by your image.

```
<ComboBox>
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="One"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Two"/>
</ComboBox>
```